# Java и web разработка

Tags: java

Добрый день. Как делать на Java сайты? Что лучше использовать jsp или jsf или spring,а может ещё что-то ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того, что вы хотите делать. Если вам нужно какие-либо простые приложения (пара страниц), то легче и уместнее использовать jsp или jsf, если нужно реализовывать более сложный проект, то Spring.

Comment: А как насчёт EJB? :-)